# GitHub API access for organizations

Tags: github, jwt, github-api, github-organizations

I want to access the private repositories in my organization using the GitHub API. You need an API token for that. For this I created a GitHub app on my organization. Then I used [this code](https://docs.github.com/de/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/generating-a-json-web-token-jwt-for-a-github-app#example-using-python-to-generate-a-jwt) from the documentation to get the token, but the generated token is not accepted and on https://jwt.io/ it says "Invalid Signature". What I have done wrong? How do I get my token to access the API?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.